# Android Upgrading app version

Tags: android, sdk, version

I have a live app on Google Play, developed against SDK v1.6 to cater for some luddites ;-) Looking at recent stats on Android (http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html), v1.6 accounts for less than 1% of all potential people, and about 1% of my users.

If in my next release, I want to take advantage of the ability to use the SD card for storing the app (SDK v2+?), will this all be handled automatically if I just develop against the newer SDK? Or should I re-launch a totally different app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT relaunch a new app! You will lose all your current customers, I would strongly recommend you to update!

Just set your ApiLevel to 2.2 and add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` to your manifest!

See also: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Going from 1.6 to 2.2 is a great choice, as app2sd is also a great feature most customers want! ;)

Hope your app rating increases that way ^^

Comment: Great stuff TK, I didn't think launching a new app was the way, but good to see such a vehement reaction to the idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.sample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```